# quickfix.Session.sendToTarget() returns "NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function"

Tags: python-3.x, quickfix

I am connecting for the first time via quickfix. Python is 3.7. Environment is Windows 7. No problems in creating the Session. Problems in sending the messages. I am totally new to this, please help.

```
import quickfix as fix
#...
settings     = fix.SessionSettings(file)
application  = FIX_IO()
storeFactory = fix.FileStoreFactory(settings)
initiator    = fix.SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings)

initiator.start()
# ALL OK WITH THE SESSION

sid = fix.SessionID('FIX.4.4', 'XXXX', 'XXXX')


print('IT DOES EXISTS:',fix.Session_doesSessionExist(sid))
#YES IT DOES
```

I successfully construct a message (as you can read below) and I print out...

```
LOGGED ON BEFORE MESSAGE: False
Logging on...
8=FIX.4.4 9=121 35=A 34=1 49=Q029 52=20190613-16:51:43.000 56=XC80 553=somelogin 554=somepassword 58=LOGON ATTEMPT 98=0 108=30 141=Y 10=015
Logging on...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bru\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\quickfix.py", line 39579, in fromAdmin
    return _quickfix.Application_fromAdmin(self, arg0, arg1)
RuntimeError: SWIG director pure virtual method called FIX::Application::fromAdmin
LOGGED ON AFTER MESSAGE: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the error message, dude!

`NotImplementedError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'Session_sendToTarget'.`

You are passing `sendToTarget` a parameter that is inappropriate, because it's the wrong type.

So, what is that parameter's type?  A Simplefix message.  And it's being passed to what function?  A QuickFIX function.

**You can't do that!** You're trying to use Toyota parts in a Ford truck.

QuickFIX doesn't know anything about Simplefix, and it certainly doesn't have any functions that take SimpleFix parameters.

So, pick one: QuickFIX or SimpleFix.  You can't use both in one app.

Comment: ok, makes senss, thanks @Grant Birchmeier. So what is the Constructor of a quickfix message?

Comment: Have you checked out the docs at quickfixengine.org?  This page specifically: http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/python/sending_messages_3.html which is linked to from http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/sending_messages.html

Comment: Please check again my question, edited. I Need a successful LOGON. Thanks

Comment: StackOverflow is probably not the best venue for this.  I highly recommend that you subscribe to the QuickFIX mailing list.  You will find a better audience there.  Plus, your snippets of code above are just not enough to really get a full picture of what you are doing.  I suggest you look at the QuickFIX example apps.  Try this one: https://github.com/quickfix/quickfix/tree/master/examples/executor/python

Comment: **Hey, don't edit your question to be something else.**  It makes the original answer look non-applicable, and your question becomes un-helpful for anyone else.  If you have a new situation, you should ask a new question.